# Always face north-up sided maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

In maps Activity, the user should not change the angle of direction which the map faces. Map should always face only north side up. How to lock the direction only to north side up and it should able to zoom-in and zoom-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Google Maps, just add

```
googleMap.uiSettings.isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
```